# Does an irreducible DTMC (s.t. $p(x,x)=0$ for all $x$) on a finite state space reaches at some finite time all states?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n\}$ be an irreducible DTMC on a finite state space $\mathbb{X}$, such that $p(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{X}$. For $y\in \mathbb{X}$, let $T_y=\inf\{k\geq 0: ~X_k=y\}.$ 
True or false: for every $x,~y\in \mathbb{X}$ we have $P(T_y<+\infty~|~X_0=x)=1.$

I believe the answer is yes (based on the assumption that $p(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{X}$). Since $p(x,x)=0$, we have that our chain reaches a state $x_1$ with probability $1$ in one step. At the 
$n-$th step our chain has reached $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, succesively, with prob. $1$. I am not that sure though why our chain reaches $y$ at some finite time.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Two states $x,~y$ communicate if $p^{(n)}(x,y)>0$ and $p^{(m)}(y,x)>0$ for some $n,~m$, and irreducible means that all states communicate. Regarding your comment on $p(x,x)$, if $p(a,b)=1/2,~p(a,a)=1/2,~p(b,c)=p(c,a)=1$ then the chain is irreducible, while having $p(a,a)\neq 0$.

Comment: What i find direct from the definitions is that for all $x,~y$ we have $P(T_y<+\infty~|~X_0=x)>0$, but why should it be equal to $1$?

Comment: This is textbook stuff: fix some $y$, then, for every $x$ there exists $p_x>0$ and $n_x$ finite such that $P_x(T_y<n_x)>p_x$. Thus there exists $p>0$ and $n$ such that $P_x(T_y>n)<1-p$. Now, using the (simple) Markov property, prove that $P_x(T_y>kn)<(1-p)^k$ for every $x$, case closed.

Comment: True. Thank you!